# Web / App Server Configuration (Nginx / uWSGI / Django)

Tags: django, nginx, server

This is probably a silly question, but for me it's not easy to find an answer.

I want to develop a web site that serves python application on aws ec2 instance.
So I think it's probably the best to use Nginx and Django with uWSGI

My question is
What is the best architecture for this system considering Scalability? and How can I do that?

At first, I thought using one Nginx server and multiple Django Application Servers, so that I can manage the resources (distribute requests to multiple application servers, since it's job can be quite heavy - recommendation based on collaborative filtering)

Now I'm developing using only one ec2 instance (tiny server)

Using architecture Nginx -> uWSGI -> Django project

So, what is the best way to split servers for load balancing? and How can I do that using Nginx?

Please let me know if this question is too ambiguous!

If you know any blot posts or books related to this question, please feel free to recommend!

Thanks!

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly interpreted your question , you want to install django application with NGINX we server. 
Refer to this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

You should let Amazon do the load balancing. Use their [application load balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) which are far easier to set up and much more performant than anything you could configure yourself.

Keep nginx and gunicorn together on each of your instances and let the ALB distribute the load beteween them.

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with AWS LB, while using load balancer from AWS, it was not draining the connection so I used nginx for the loadbalancing and it it serving well on a single server for multi-backend gunicorn nodes.

you can use least_conn parameter in upstream to resolve your purpose and it is quite fast as well, since it looks for the least connections in cluster.

```
upstream <upstream_name> {
  least_conn;
  server 192.168.1.1:3000 fail_timeout=10s;
  server 192.168.1.2:3000 fail_timeout=10s;
  }
```

upstream_name will be the name you are passing via proxy_pass